# How to do a 'mock up' event or prolfile form without it going 'live' on the website?

Tags: civievent, forms

I have just started using CiviCRM so I am still finding my way around. Is there a way to create, for example, an event or a newsletter sign-up form and see what it would look like on the website without making it go live on the net? Someone else takes care of our website, I just do CiviCRM, so I don't want to mess up our website while I am still figuring out how to use Civi!

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

-Mia

Answer (score 3):

On the first step when creating a new event, down near the bottom of the form, there is a checkbox labelled "Is this Event Active?" Un-check this and the event will be hidden from the public. You can come back later to set to true -- it's on the first tab when configuring the event.

To display the event on a WordPress / CiviCRM site you need to insert a shortcode for the event into a WordPress post. Put your cursor into the body of the post, then click on the CiviCRM triangular icon just above the field. Choose appropriate options like an event and test rather live page. That will let you test purchasing a ticket for the event without having to pay real money. Test tickets purchased also dont show up in standard reports and participant counts. When you are satisfied with the purchase pages and emails sent you should switch the shortcode to the live page and ènable the  event.

Good luck.

Comment: Great! Thank you! I will keep an eye out for the check-box.

Comment: See more detail in edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

What Drupal or Wordpress or some other crm?

From the civi side of things, you can make the event & keep it non-active  and use the test and live links from the backend to get a general feeling of it, but depending on your configuration, you might not see it full integrated on the front end.

Comment: Wordpress. Can you say more about 'test and live links' please?